# How to apply ffill to 1?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below,

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0
2  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  0
```

I want to convert this into like this,

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  1  1  0  0
2  1  1  0  0
3  1  1  1  0
```

so far I tried,

```
df= df.replace('0',np.NaN)
df=df.fillna(method='ffill').fillna('0')
```

my above code works fine,

But I think there is some other better approach to solve this problem,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) with data converted to numeric and then replace by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.mask(df.astype(int).cumsum() >= 1, '1')
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  1  1  0  0
2  1  1  0  0
3  1  1  1  0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.astype(int).cumsum())
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  1  1  0  0
2  1  2  0  0
3  1  2  1  0
```

Or same principe in `numpy` with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
arr = df.values.astype(int)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(np.cumsum(arr, axis=0) >= 1, '1', '0'), 
                  index=df.index, 
                  columns= df.columns)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  1  1  0  0
2  1  1  0  0
3  1  1  1  0
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution